# Lenovo touchpad becomes very slow in random intervals on Kubuntu

Tags: touchpad, kubuntu, synaptic

I just installed a fresh Kubuntu on my Ideapad 3. The touchpad was working fine but then after a while, I noticed it became very slow and hard to move in random instances and then it went back to normal.

After installation of the OS I have only done 2 things that may contribute to this problem:

1. I changed trackpad settings, made it faster.
2. I installed a driver package `sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

How can I troubleshoot this?